# How to enable Powerpoint, Review, Start Inking in ribbon

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I love the inking tool in Powerpoint, which I regularly use to highlight points of interest in screenshots.

[image]

But for mysterious reasons, sometimes the tool is missing in the ribbon:

[image]

After endless googling without success, now I observed that the tool is always missing after a fresh system boot, but is present after locking and unlocking the screen!

(Office 2013)

Comment: This suggestion won't help you work out what/why, but did you try a repair/re-installation?